# CSS3: translate vs. translateX

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I was looking over the source code to [**swipe.js**](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/blob/master/swipe.js), a cross-browser library for creating animated slideshows on devices that support touch.

To create the animation, swipe.js uses CSS3 transforms (and falls back on Javascript animation if it has to.)  So, the translate function they use to do the actual CSS3 transform is:

```
 function translate(index, dist, speed) {

    var slide = slides[index];
    var style = slide && slide.style;

    if (!style) return;

    style.webkitTransitionDuration =
    style.MozTransitionDuration =
    style.msTransitionDuration =
    style.OTransitionDuration =
    style.transitionDuration = speed + 'ms';

    style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + dist + 'px,0)' + 'translateZ(0)';
    style.msTransform =
    style.MozTransform =
    style.OTransform = 'translateX(' + dist + 'px)';

  }
```

So, basically in order to make this cross-browser, they have to set different transform properties for Webkit, Mozilla, Microsoft and Opera.  What I don't understand is why they use the `translate` function (which takes two arguments) for webkit, and the single-argument `translateX` function for everything else.

As far as I can see from the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation, both engines support `translate` as well as `translateX`.  Is there some reason the author of swipe.js decided to use `translateX` for non-webkit browsers here?  Is there actually some browser out there that supports `translateX` but NOT `translate`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has historical reasons, by the time [support for Firefox, Opera and IE was added](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/commit/7a80b5e72fc6485f6a1faa05d80a0c1b5b196871), they all [supported only 2d transforms](http://caniuse.com/transforms3d). Support for 3d transforms was [added a few months later in firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/10.0/releasenotes/), and IE10 also supports it, so it's actually only still neccessary for Opera, but I guess it's left there for backwards compatibility.

**Update**

Oops, thought I've read `translate3d`, but in the later verions it's only `translate`, just like you've posted it. So, it looks like they've [changed to `translate` + `translateZ`](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/commit/87ea9d69766767d22eb83571becf1d94e32621f3) because `translate3d` would [no longer trigger hardware acceleration in iOS6](http://indiegamr.com/ios6-html-hardware-acceleration-changes-and-how-to-fix-them/), maybe there are similar problems with `translateX`.